# Spring JPA ORM relationships with multiple persistence units

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I built app with Spring+Hibernate+Spring Data JPA+PostgreSQL. I have Person class referenced to Marital class at two different resources.

- Person has tx_person table at database pg_land.
- Marital has tx_marital table at database pg_master.

I could retrieved each other when no relationships between Person and Marital. Problem occured when I built relationships (@ManyToOne and @OneToMany) between two classes.

**Test Class**

```
package id.co.p**g.sandbox;

import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;    
import id.co.p**g.land.Person;
import id.co.p**g.service.land.PersonService;

public class PersonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:spring-data-app-context.xml");
        ctx.load("classpath:datasource.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        PersonService personService = ctx.getBean(
                "springJpaPersonService", PersonService.class);

        Page<Person> requests = personService.getPerson(1);
        listSurveys(requests);

    }


    private static void listSurveys(Page<Person> requests) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("List of person");
        for(Person request: requests) {
            System.out.println(request);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property no found for type id.co.palmagroup.land.Person
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:325)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:305)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:269)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:240)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:427)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:390)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:457)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:438)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:320)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at id.co.palmagroup.service.land.PersonImpl.getPerson(PersonImpl.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.getPerson(Unknown Source)
    at id.co.palmagroup.sandbox.PersonTest.main(PersonTest.java:20)
```

**Person Class**

```
package id.co.p**g.land;

import id.co.p**g.master.Marital;

import java.util.UUID;    
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;    
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tx_person")
public class Person {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private Marital marital;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    @Column(name = "id")    
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotEmpty(message="{validation.formcode.NotEmpty.message}")
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Marital.class)  
    @JoinColumn(name="id_marital")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    public Marital getMarital() {
        return marital;
    }

    public void setMarital(Marital marital) {
        this.marital = marital;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person ID: " + id
                + ". Name: " + name
                + ". Marital: " + marital;
    }
}
```

**Marital Class**

```
package id.co.p**g.master;

import id.co.p**g.land.Person;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "m_marital")
public class Marital implements Serializable {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private String description; 
    private int no;
    private Set<Person> persons;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    @Column(name = "id")    
    public UUID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Person.class, mappedBy="marital")
    public Set<Person> getPersons() {
        return this.persons;
    }

    @Column(name="no")
    public int getNo() {
        return no;
    }

    public void setNo(int no) {
        this.no = no;
    }

    public void setPersons(Set<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return + no + ". "
                + "Marital ID: " + id 
                + " Name: " + name
                + ". Description: " + description;
    }
}
```

**Person Implementation Class**

```
package id.co.p**g.service.land;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;    
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;    
import id.co.p**g.land.Person;
import id.co.p**g.repository.land.PersonRepository;

@Service("springJpaPersonService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonImpl implements PersonService {
    // TODO PAGE_SIZE, rubah menjadi konfigurasi parameter.
    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="landPersistence")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(personRepository.findAll());
    }

    public Person save(Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public void delete(Person person) {
        personRepository.delete(person);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Person findById(UUID id) {
        return personRepository.findById(id);
    }


    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Page<Person> findAllByPage(Pageable pageable) {
        return personRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Person> getPerson(Integer pagenumber) {
        PageRequest pagerequest = new PageRequest(pagenumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE, Sort.Direction.ASC, "no");
        return personRepository.findAll(pagerequest);
    }
}
```

**Marital Implementation Class**

```
package id.co.p**g.service.master;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;    
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;    
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;    
import id.co.p**g.master.Marital;
import id.co.p**g.repository.master.MaritalRepository;

@Service("springJpaMaritalService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class MaritalImpl implements MaritalService {
    // TODO PAGE_SIZE, rubah menjadi konfigurasi parameter.
    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    @Autowired
    private MaritalRepository maritalRepository;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="masterPersistence")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Marital> findAll() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(maritalRepository.findAll());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Marital findById(UUID id) {
        return maritalRepository.findById(id);
    }


    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Page<Marital> findAllByPage(Pageable pageable) {
        return maritalRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Marital> getMarital(Integer pagenumber) {
        PageRequest pagerequest = new PageRequest(pagenumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE, Sort.Direction.ASC, "name");
        return maritalRepository.findAll(pagerequest);
    }
}
```

**Application Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- LAND -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="landPersistence"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="id.co.p**g.*" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- MASTER -->
    <bean id="transactionManagerMaster" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emfMaster" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerMaster" />

    <bean id="emfMaster"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="masterPersistence"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMaster" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="id.co.p**g.*" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="id.co.p**g.service.*" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="id.co.p**g.repository.land"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="id.co.p**g.repository.master"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="emfMaster" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManagerMaster" />

</beans>
```

**Data Source Configuration File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pg_land" />
        <property name="username" value="sysland" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceMaster"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pg_master" />
        <property name="username" value="usermaster" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: You can't have associations between entities of different persistence units. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Then what is the common solution when an application has to access 2 different databases?

Comment: To have 2 persistence units, using entities having no cross-persistence-unit associations.

Comment: "using entities having no cross-persistenc-unit associations" - does it mean that both Person and Marital should be at the same database? As my early objective is to keep master data at separate database.

Comment: It's up to you to choose where you store your data. But you won't be able to have associations between entities in two different persistence units.

Answer (score 0):

I use different associations in different database. 
Mark the relationship with @ transient and just put the id of the entity. 
when you will need to refer to the id of the entity at the other database. just use a find

Comment: Do you have a web page detailed explanation about this? I used hibernate-entitymanager 3.6.8.Final.